# ggplot2: uniform color scale across many plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to make several plots with the same color scale across all the plots.  Is there any way to tell the scale_color_gradientn that, for example, -10 maps to green and 10 maps to red, even if the data don't contain those values?

Here's an example that shows the problem.  In the first plot green indicates 5, in the second plot green is 15.  I want green to indicate the same value, say 10, in both plots.

```
library( ggplot2)

xa <- ya <- za <- 0:9
xb <- yb <- zb <- 10:19

fma <- data.frame( xa, ya, za)
fmb <- data.frame( xb, yb, zb)

ggplot( fma) +
  geom_point( aes( xa, ya, col=za), size=5) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(
    name='someName',
    colours=c('#0000ff', '#00ff00', '#ff0000'))

dev.new()

ggplot( fmb) +
  geom_point( aes( xb, yb, col=zb), size=5) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(
    name='someName',
    colours=c('#0000ff', '#00ff00', '#ff0000'))
```

Here is a kluge to work around the problem:

```
# Have fmlim contain the overall min,max, and
# plot fmlim using geom_blank.

library( ggplot2)

xa <- ya <- za <- 0:9
xb <- yb <- zb <- 10:19

fma <- data.frame( xa, ya, za)
fmb <- data.frame( xb, yb, zb)

fmlim <- data.frame(
  xa=rep(xa[1], 2),
  ya=rep(ya[1], 2),
  xb=rep(xb[1], 2),
  yb=rep(yb[1], 2),
  zlims=c( min( za, zb), max( za, zb)))

ggplot( fma) +
  geom_point( aes( xa, ya, col=za), size=5) +
  geom_blank( aes( xa, ya, col=zlims), data=fmlim) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(
    name='someName',
    colours=c('#0000ff', '#00ff00', '#ff0000'))

dev.new()

ggplot( fmb) +
  geom_point( aes( xb, yb, col=zb), size=5) +
  geom_blank( aes( xb, yb, col=zlims), data=fmlim) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(
    name='someName',
    colours=c('#0000ff', '#00ff00', '#ff0000'))
```

Now green indicates 10 in both plots, which is great.  But it's a kluge.

Is there a way to tell scale_colour_gradientn that specific data values map to specific colors?  I tried using "values", but that mapping changes with the data values being plotted.

Thanks!

Comment: can you set explicit `limits`?

Comment: Thank you Ben Bolker!  "limits" works well.

Comment: feel free to write that up as an answer ...